# Best matches for a partially specified word in Python

Tags: python

I have a file dict.txt that has all words in the English language.

The user will input their word:

`x = raw_input("Enter partial word: ")`

Example inputs would be: r-n, --n, -u-, he--o, h-llo and so on, unknown characters would be specified by a underscore preferably instead of (-).

I want the program to come up with a list, of all the best matches that are found in the dictionary.

Example: If partial word was r--, the list would contain run, ran, rat, rob and so on.

Is there any way to do this using for loops?

Comment: what's your question? what have to tried, what was the outcome?

Comment: The answer is "Yes, you can do this using for loops".  Can you come up with a more targeted question?  Perhaps one that shows you've thought about the problem or tried something?

Comment: Why do u want to use for loop ? Is that part of the question/homework ?

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to do this would be by using [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). Since it is unclear whether this question is homework, the details are left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using _ to denote wildcards, use \w instead. Add \b to the beginning and end of the pattern, then just run the dictionary through a regexp matcher. So -un--- becomes:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\b\wun\w\w\w\b', "run runner bunt bunter bunted bummer")
['runner', 'bunter', 'bunted']
```

\w matches any 'word character'. \b matches any word boundary.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this repeatedly you should create a index:

```
wordlist = [word.strip() for word in "run, ran, rat, rob, fish, tree".split(',')]

from collections import defaultdict

class Index(object):

    def __init__(self, wordlist=()):
        self.trie = defaultdict(set)
        for word in wordlist:
            self.add_word(word)

    def add_word(self, word):
        """ adds word to the index """
        # save the length of the word
        self.trie[len(word)].add(word)    
        for marker in enumerate(word):
            # add word to the set of words with (pos,char)
            self.trie[marker].add(word)


    def find(self, pattern, wildcard='-' ):
        # get all word with matching length as candidates
        candidates = self.trie[len(pattern)]

        # get all words with all the markers
        for marker in enumerate(pattern):            
            if marker[1] != wildcard:
                candidates &= self.trie[marker]

            # exit early if there are no candicates
            if not candidates:                
                return None

        return candidates


with open('dict.txt', 'rt') as lines:
    wordlist = [word.strip() for word in lines]

s = Index(wordlist)
print s.find("r--")
```

[Tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) are made for searching strings. This is a simple prefix trie, using a single dict.

Answer (score 0):

A few approaches occur to me;

The first is to preprocess your dictionary into words[wordlength][offset][charAtOffset] = set(matching words); then your query becomes an intersection of all relevant word-sets. Very fast, but memory-intensive and a lot of set-up work.

Ex:

```
# search for 'r-n'
matches = list(words[3][0]['r'] & words[3][2]['n'])
```

The second is a linear scan of the dictionary using regular expressions; much slower, but minimal memory footprint.

Ex:

```
import re

foundMatch = re.compile('r.n').match
matches = [word for word in allWords if foundMatch(word)]
```

Third would be a recursive search into a word-Trie;

Fourth - and it sounds like what you want - is a naive word-matcher:

```
with open('dictionary.txt') as inf:
    all_words = [word.strip().lower() for word in inf]  # one word per line

find_word = 'r-tt-r'
matching_words = []
for word in all_words:
    if len(word)==len(find_word):
        if all(find==ch or find=='-' for find,ch in zip(find_word, word)):
            matching_words.append(word)
```

**Edit**: full code for the first option follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import operator

try:
    inp = raw_input    # Python 2.x
except NameError:
    inp = input        # Python 3.x

class Words(object):
    @classmethod
    def fromFile(cls, fname):
        with open(fname) as inf:
            return cls(inf)

    def __init__(self, words=None):
        super(Words,self).__init__()
        self.words = set()
        self.index = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set)))
        _addword = self.addWord
        for word in words:
            _addword(word.strip().lower())

    def addWord(self, word):
        self.words.add(word)
        _ind = self.index[len(word)]
        for ind,ch in enumerate(word):
            _ind[ind][ch].add(word)

    def findAll(self, pattern):
        pattern = pattern.strip().lower()
        _ind = self.index[len(pattern)]
        return reduce(operator.__and__, (_ind[ind][ch] for ind,ch in enumerate(pattern) if ch!='-'), self.words)

def main():
    print('Loading dict... ')
    words = Words.fromFile('dict.txt')
    print('done.')

    while True:
        seek = inp('Enter partial word ("-" is wildcard, nothing to exit): ').strip()
        if seek:
            print("Matching words: "+' '.join(words.findAll(seek))+'\n')
        else:
            break

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like homework involving searching algorithms or something, but I'll give you a start.

One solution might be to index the file (if this can be done in a reasonable time) into a tree structure with  each character representing a node value and each child being all subsequent characters.  You could then traverse the tree using the input as a map.  A character represents the next node to go to and a dash represents that it should include all child nodes.  Every time you hit a leaf n levels deeps with n being the length of the input you know you've found a match.

The nice thing is that once you index, your search will speed up considerably.  It's the indexing that can take forever...

Answer (score 0):

Takes a bit of memory but this does the trick:

```
import re
import sys

word = '\\b' + sys.argv[1].replace('-', '\\w') + '\\b'
print word

with open('data.txt', 'r') as fh:
    print re.findall(word, fh.read())
```